# Android studio > create new project > Google Play Services Activity: What is this?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, google-play-services

I'm using Android Studio for the first time, and when I create a new project I get a window which asks me what activity I want to add. One option is a "Google Play Services Activity".

What is it for? What does it do? I hope this isn't a stupid question, it feels like it is, but I can't find an answer. I have done some Android development a while ago so understand Activities and so on.  I am finding information on "Google Play Services" but I don't understand what the Activity does.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android studio creates a new activity that initiates and connect to google play Services unified client . it allows you to enable (google games services ,google + api , google drive api,google wallet api ... ) you can use that activity templates if in you application you want to integrate with any of the services mentioned above

Read More here : https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html

Answer (score -2):

I think it's an activity that simply check if your Google Play Services are currenctly initialized